# OpenTK. Trouble with mirror reflection

Tags: reflection

I have some problems with rendering of mirror reflection in OpenTK. I need to see reflection of objects only from one side from my mirror, but my program also gives reflection from another side and it hides the first one. Could you help me?

```
        private void glControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loaded = true;

            GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue);
            initRendering();

            Matrix4 p = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)(80 * Math.PI / 180), 1, 20, 500);
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.LoadMatrix(ref p);

            Matrix4 modelview = Matrix4.LookAt(70, 70, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadMatrix(ref modelview);
        }

        private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!loaded)
                return;

            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            drawScene();

            /*axes*/
            GL.Color3(Color.Black);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Lines);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(70, 0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 70, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 70);
            GL.End();

            glControl1.SwapBuffers();
        }

        void initRendering()
        {
            GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Flat);

            GL.ClearDepth(1.0f);
            GL.ClearStencil(0);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal);
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.AutoNormal);
            // Setup the drawing area and shading mode
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.LoadIdentity();


            GL.Enable(EnableCap.PointSmooth);
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadIdentity();

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
            GL.LightModel(LightModelParameter.LightModelAmbient, ambientLight);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Normalize);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);
        }

        public class CustomOpenGLControl : GLControl
        {
            public CustomOpenGLControl()
                : base(new OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode(32, 24, 8))
            {

            }
        }

        private void drawFrame()
        {
            GL.Color3(Color.Red);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
            GL.Normal3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            for (int i = 0; i < upWall.Length; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(upWall[i].x, upWall[i].y, upWall[i].z);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
            GL.Normal3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            for (int i = 0; i < downWall.Length; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(downWall[i].x, downWall[i].y, downWall[i].z);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.Color3(Color.Green);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
            GL.Normal3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            for (int i = 0; i < backWall.Length; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(backWall[i].x, backWall[i].y, backWall[i].z);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.Color3(Color.Blue);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
            GL.Normal3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            for (int i = 0; i < rightWall.Length; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(rightWall[i].x, rightWall[i].y, rightWall[i].z);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.Color3(Color.Orange);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
            GL.Normal3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            for (int i = 0; i < leftWall.Length; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(leftWall[i].x, leftWall[i].y, leftWall[i].z);
            }
            GL.End();
        }

        private void drawMirror()
        {
            GL.PushMatrix();

            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
            GL.Normal3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            for (int i = 0; i < mirror.Length; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(mirror[i].x, mirror[i].y, mirror[i].z);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.PopMatrix();
        }

        private void drawScene()
        {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.AccumBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.StencilBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
            double[] eqr = { 0f, y0 + height / 6f, 0f, 0.0f };

            GL.PushMatrix();

            GL.ColorMask(false, false, false, false);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.StencilTest);
            GL.StencilFunc(StencilFunction.Always, 1, 1);
            GL.StencilOp(StencilOp.Keep, StencilOp.Keep, StencilOp.Replace);
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            drawMirror();
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.ColorMask(true, true, true, true);
            GL.StencilFunc(StencilFunction.Equal, 1, 1);
            GL.StencilOp(StencilOp.Keep, StencilOp.Keep, StencilOp.Keep);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.ClipPlane0);
            GL.ClipPlane(ClipPlaneName.ClipPlane0, eqr);
            GL.PushMatrix();
            GL.Scale(1, -1, 1);
            drawFrame();
            GL.PopMatrix();
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.ClipPlane0);
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.StencilTest);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
            GL.Color4(1, 1, 1, 0.3f);
            GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
            drawMirror();
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
            drawFrame();
            GL.PopMatrix();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you isolate the code that you are having problems with?

Comment: Yeah. I think, the problem is in methods 'drawScene'. Also i tried attach some pictures, but i have too little reputation for this.

Comment: here is the link to result of my program
http://www.gamedev.ru/files/images/104924_1425242717_snimok.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cant help too much with this. I would run your code, but unfortunately I am not at my programming computer right now, and I don't have any experience with opentk.

Comment: As i understand, openTK is the same openGL